# setImage: forState: lagging the UI

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, uiimage, grand-central-dispatch

I have a tableview which runs some code for fetching a UIImage from NSData in a background thread, then in the foreground it calls `[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];`.

The problem is that it freezes the UI for a split second on that line, until it's complete. This means that the UI freezes while it sets it as the image. Because the user is scrolling, this is very noticeable and jittery. Is there any way to avoid my UI from freezing like this?

```
dispatch_queue_t cellSetupQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Setup", NULL);
dispatch_async(cellSetupQueue, ^{
    UIImage *image = [self.mediaDelegate largeThumbnailForMediaAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{     
        [self.thumbnailButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    });
});

dispatch_release(cellSetupQueue);
```

Comment: we will need `setThumbnailToImage:animated:` as-well

Comment: @vikingosegundo Oh, that goes to a method with literally just the setImage code in, so replaced it with that line.

Comment: you say, you set the images while scrolling. I assume, this code is inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Does every cell have it's own `mediaDelegate`, or do they share?

Comment: than there is a good chance, that you have a bottleneck there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing your images are JPGs. If so then UIImage will defer decoding the actual image until the first time it actually needs those pixels. Check out the ImageIO framework for more precise control on this. Here's a snippet I use:

```
CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)data, NULL); // data is your image file NSData
if (source)
{
    NSDictionary *dict = @{ (__bridge NSString *)kCGImageSourceShouldCache : @(YES) };
    CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, 0, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)dict);
    if (cgImage)
    {
        CFRelease(source);
        return cgImage; // you can keep this reference so you dont have to decode again later
    }
}
```

The important part is the `kCGImageSourceShouldCache` option. You can run this code on the background thread and pass the decoded image to the UI thread.

Comment: This is great, thanks. So if the `[self.mediaDelegate largeThumbnailForMediaAtIndex:indexPath.row];` method passes a UIImage, how do I work that UIImage into the code above?

Comment: It would be better if you change `largeThumbnailForMediaAtIndex:` to load the image from file, then create the UIImage from the CGImageRef returned by CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex.

Comment: I used this code, and did `[UIImage imageWithCGImage:];` on the image I got from it, but it still had the same freezing loading the image into the UI on the main thread. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Are you calling `imageWithCGImage:` on the background thread? Also, have you measured the performance before and after you used this method?